# Group Email, different users of the group should receive the group emails at different times in the day

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have a group email setup with office 365 but I'm trying to find a way to set up that between 6pm to 1pm one user of the group should receive the emails and between 1pm to 6pm a different user should.

Thank You, Sol

Comment: I'm afraid this is not realized on both Outlook client side and Office 365 side.

Comment: I think there should be another way to do it, create a rule that reads the time in the header of the email. I just don't know how to write that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I also thought of this. Delete emails during specific time on users' client. But I thought it may cause confusions if numbers are also included in the email content. They may miss some emails.

For example, format of time is "14:31:02". So, we may need to add “14:” to the rule condition.

[image]

So emails received during that time will be deleted automatically. Users won't see them.